# How to design HTML 5 audio player

Tags: html, html5-audio

I need to design my html 5 audio player with css. i don't know how to approach that. please suggest me the best solutions to design the html audio player.

Comment: There are lots of websites for tutorials. Check this out : http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-a-customized-html5-audio-player--webdesign-7081

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use http://jplayer.org/ its customizable!